# Why can there be no (finite-sheeted) common cover of the torus and the figure eight?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Why can there not be a space $W$ so that $(W,p)$ is a covering of $T^2$ and $(W,q)$ is a covering of $\infty$ (used here to denote the figure eight space) and *both covers are finite-sheeted*?

We have $\pi_1(T^2) = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, and $\pi_1(\infty) = \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$.
Covering space theory tells us that we must have $p_*(\pi_1(W))$ a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ of finite index (because of finitely-sheeted) and $q_*(\pi_1(W))$ a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$ of finite index.

Now, I'm aware the subgroups of free groups are free, and subgroups of free abelian groups are free abelian, but since we're considering *different homomorphic images* of the group $\pi_1(W)$, I don't know where the contradiction is. I'm also unsure of where finite index / finite-sheeted comes into play.

Comment: Do you mean for $W$ to be a "thickened" figure 8 which is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?  Otherwise $W$ and $T^2$ are not even locally homeomorphic so they certainly cannot have a common covering space, finite-sheeted or not.

Comment: On top of what Eric said, note that $p_\ast$ is always injective.

Comment: Show that every subgroup of $F_2$ of finite index is nonabelian; equivalently, it's free of rank at least $2$.